# Send JSON request from Android

Tags: php, android, json, httprequest, gson

I'm trying to send a JSON object to retrieve some data. inside the JSON object is the year, type, and country parameter to get from the database. But the server doesn't seem to get the value that I passed on.

Here is my Android code :

```
public HttpResponse makeRequest(String uri, String json) {
    try {
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(uri);
        request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.d("tes", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("tes", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("tes", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("tes", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Map<String, String> comment = new HashMap<String, String>();
    comment.put("country", "Indonesia");
    comment.put("year", "2014");
    comment.put("type", "Audax");
    String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment, Map.class);
    Log.d("sent json",json);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = makeRequest("http://racehub.me/mobile/native_races", json);

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
        if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
            instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
        }

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        Log.d("tes", builder.toString());

        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());
        JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);

        return finalResult;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("fail", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("fail", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("tes", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the logcat, I saw the sent JSON was (it looked okay):

```
D/sent json﹕ {"type":"All","year":"2014","country":"All"}
```

And here is the PHP that receive the JSON and return the result from the database

```
function native_races($f3) {
        $table_series=new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'),'series');

        $country = $f3->clean($f3->get('GET.country'));
        $type = $f3->clean($f3->get('GET.type'));
        $year = $f3->clean($f3->get('GET.year'));

        $races = MainModel::getRaceList($f3, $country, $type, $year);

        echo json_encode($races);
    }
```

Comment: This is Duplicate Question and u may read this tutorial for more [details]( http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/) and http://mongskiewl.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/sending-json-data-from-android-to-a-php-script/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I cannot use GET method to send JSON, and I use the normal GET method in the end

```
 String url = "http://racehub.me/mobile/native_races?";

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", "all"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", "2014"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "all"));
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");

            url += paramString; 
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
            request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
            request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request);
```